# VisualStudio Code(1.70.1 version) Issue or ? - No Compile Check for ".cs" files (C# Language)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Recently I updated my Visual Studio Code to a new version(1.70.1 - system setup), but it seems that I encounter some problems.

So after the update, seems that there is no compile check for the cs files. (C# language)
Also after I right click - "Go to definition" it's missing.

Any recommendations ? Or what happened ? I reinstalled my omnisharp extension, but it didn't fix the issue.

*(first update)As an update I reinstalled the VS Code with the system setup that is on their website to 1.71.0 and nothing, still the same issue. I wonder if anybody that is using C# is having this issue.
*(second update) I did downgrade to an older version from January - VS CODE System 1.64.2 and reinstalled my omnisharper and now it works again. (Compile check and other things that is used in vs studio)

Conclusion: If you have the same problem, downgrade to an older version of vs code. That worked for me. (or there was a setting that I missed for the new vs code 1.71.0, please let me know)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an earlier version of .NET than .NET 6, see if making the value of `omnisharp.useModernNet` to `false` will fix it.

Also ensure you can access the `dotnet` command in VS Code terminal.

And see if you have the setting `omnisharp.autoStart` set to `false` by mistake.

You can force Omnisharp loading by bringing the command window (CTRL+SHFIT+P or CMD+SHFIT+P) and choosing `Omnisharp: Select Project` then picking a `.sln` or `.csproj` file.